# Stats.aspx page in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, admin-pages

I wanted to understand how does `stats.aspx` page work in Sitecore? is there any specific setting that needs to be done to get Site specific renderings? Sometimes when I visit the Admin page - stats.aspx I can see my Website being listed there and sometimes I just see "`shell` ". How can I get my website tab listed there?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only see `stats.aspx` (and other Sitecore admin pages) on CM server.

Stats are collected according to `Sitecore.Context.Site`, so when you see only `shell` page in stats page, that means that since last restart of your CM server (or since the last time one clicked `Reset` on stats page), the only visited site on CM server was Sitecore backend.

You will not see any stats from CD servers.

So unless you're using Standalone setup, you won't really see any "live" starts from your client facing websites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sitecore stats page to collect information about rendering.

The stats page provides the following information about the various renderings used in a page, or throughout the website — depending when the stats page is observed.

- **Rendering** — The name of the rendering.
- **Site** — The name of the website that the information for the rendering is being collected.
- **Count** — The number of times that the rendering has been called since the last time the stats page was reset.
- **From cache** — The number of times the rendering was pulled from cache.
- **Avg. time (ms)** — The average time taken to render to output.
- **Avg. items** — The average number of items included in the rendering.
- **Max. time** — The maximum amount of time taken to render the output.
- **Max. items** — The maximum number of items included in the rendering.
- **Total time** — The total amount of time taken for all instances of this rendering since the last stats page reset occurred.
- **Total items** — The total number of items included in all instances of this rendering since the last stats page reset occurred.
- **Last run** — This the last time that stats were collected.

Few key points to understand are:

1. The stats window shows information about the renderings that have been requested since the last time the stats page was reset.

   If you want to start from scratch, click the refresh button — for
   example, if you want to view information regarding an individual web
   page you must clear out the stats page.
2. If you wish to view rendering stats that have been collected since the last reset, use the
   information presented.
3. If you wish to collect information about a single page, reset the stats page. In the site window,
   go to the website or webpage that you are going to collect stats about the renderings it
   includes.

   **Note**
   To collect information about caching and averages, make several calls to the page.

For more details refer to section `2.3 Rendering Performance`: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/legacy-docs/SC75/cms-diagnostics-guide-sc70-a4.pdf

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

An addition to @marek's answer above.

Although the page is only available on a CM server, the output of the `stats.aspx` page is saved, by default, to `App_Config\diagnostics\health_monitor`, every 10 minutes, and kept for seven days. This is configured in `App_Config\Sitecore\CMS.Core\Sitecore.Diagnostics.config`.

The report will have a name like: `RenderingStatistics.YYYYMMDD.FFFFFFZ.html`. The output of the `cache.aspx` page is saved as `CacheStatus.YYYYMMDD.FFFFFFZ.html`. This is to allow monitoring of cache and rendering statistics on production environments.